# Button setOnClickListener not working with many layouts

Tags: java, android, xml

I've made many LinearLayout as I want to make it suitable with any size of device. But the problem is now that setOnClickListener is not working when I click the button that I've put inside the layouts.

Here is my XML

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.52"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.48"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.65"
                android:baselineAligned="false">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.64"
                    android:baselineAligned="false">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.7"/>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.3">

                        <Button
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:id="@+id/wordlist_btn" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.36"
                    android:baselineAligned="false">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.2">
                        <Button
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:id="@+id/livingroom_btn"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.8"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.35" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

My Java

```
package app.magiscamp.meinhaus;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button word_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.wordlist_btn);
        Button living_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.livingroom_btn);
        word_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        living_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        word_btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);    
        living_btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        word_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wordlist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        });

        living_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wordlist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "not working" means that you don't see the `Toast`s, then that's because you're not calling `show()` on the `Toast`s you created.

Change the `onClick()`s to something like

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wordlist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have forgotten to call `show()` in Toast

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wordlist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

add .show() in your Toast like this

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wordlist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```